# Почему не подключается класс?

Tags: php, namespace

Почему у меня все работает в файле public/index.php:

```
use Controller\ClientsController;
$myControl = new ClientsController();
$myControl->hello();
```

а если я подключу вместо этой иницилизации вспомогательный файл all.php , в который вставлю эти же самые строки объявления класса:

```
use Controller\ClientsController;
require "../src/routes/all.php";
```

То в нем класс ClientsController не находится? По сути код файл all.php вставляется в index.php и при этом все должно работать нормально, неужели путь влияет на это? В чем подвох?
Структура проекта:

```
`-classes
--ClientsController.php
-public/
--index.php
-src/
--routes/
---all.php
`
```

Comment: что именно значит "не находится"?

Comment: Это значит:
Fatal error: Class 'ClientsController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\goodfood\src\routes\all.php on line 17

Comment: Приведет код полностью, пожалуйста

Comment: Вы сперва пишете `use Controller\ClientsController`, а потом `require`. Попробуйте поменять строки местами.

Comment: В первом сообщении есть все основное. 
Вот содержимое classes/ClientsController.php:

`<?php
    namespace Controller;

    class ClientsController {
        public function hello()
        {
           echo "Hello true class";
        }
    }

?>`

Comment: @Pavel Sokolov, вы не поняли. В require я подключаю файл из другой директории, который содержит всего 2 строки: 
`$myControl = new ClientsController();
$myControl->hello();`

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите абсолютный путь, вместо 2 точек

```
require "../src/routes/all.php";
```

Comment: Все равно пишет:
Fatal error: Class 'ClientsController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\goodfood\src\routes\all.php on line 17

Comment: И да, сначала require , потом use

Comment: да вы не поняли, `require... all.php` подключает файл, в котором юзается класс ClientsController

Comment: Если я подключу его ниже, то в all.php никак не найдется этот класс. Но проблема в том, что он так и так не видится - в этом главный вопрос

Comment: если вместо require на его же месте написать:
`use Controller\ClientsController;
require "../src/routes/all.php";
`
то все сработает, но как в подключаемом файле заставить все работать?